# High CPU within Object.wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, cpu-usage

I have a typical conditional variable implemented in Java's fundamental synchronized/wait:

```
ConcurrentHashMap incompleted = ...;

// the notifier
incompleted.remove(key);
synchronized (this) {
  if (incompleted.isEmpty()) {
     notifyAll();
  }
}

// the waiter
synchronized (this) { // one this object for each request
   while (!incompleted.isEmpty()) {
     wait(10000L); // this is exact time out pass in
   }
   // done and exit
}
```

These codes look very typical and work. However, when I test with many (say 100) concurrent requests, the CPU load is at about 80% and the profiler reports 80% times the app spends in the wait() method. Usually high cpu may be due to busy waiting in the app code. But why would wait() itself spent all the times? Thanks

The host is an VMware host, running Oracle JVM 1.6.

Comment: Is this just an experiment? Because if this is real code you should use the new `Lock` and `Condition` rather than `synchronized` and `wait`/`notify`.

Comment: Why @bmorris591?  What's wrong with the standard mechanisms?

Comment: @Gray There's nothing wrong with them but the new mechanisms are now accepted best practice.

Comment: I would certainly argue with "accepted".  Care to provide references to back that up @bmorris591?

Comment: The new library just does the same thing. In fact, if I commented out this particular wait() block. The same high CPU goes to another wait() on some totally unrelated codes. One thing I should add, the host is a VMware. Though I wrote small test program that does the synchronized()/wait() and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

> why would wait() itself spent all the times?

It may be that your profiler is showing your wall-clock times and *not* CPU cycles.  Your threads are spending most of their time in `wait()`, yes, but are not consuming CPU resources doing so.

If the profiler *is* showing CPU cycles then you should consider switching to `notify()` instead of `notifyAll()`.  If only one thread will be able to de-queue something, there is no reason to wake up all 100 of your threads.

Comment: hmm.. I can try. though there is really only one thread waiting. It is also not likely the problem of profiler per se since the system also reports high cpu usages. It is not high percentage of low overall cpu load.

Answer (score 0):

OK, my mistake. in this profiler, the first view is the wall clock time. I mistaken it as cpu burn time. but then why would I get almost 100% wall time in Object.wait() but still high cpu load. maybe that's for another question.